# How to code same step in Power shell

Tags: powershell

I have code in Perl like this

```
$rc = `D:\\EmailConnector\\run.bat > $emailconnecter_log;`; 
    if ( $? / 256 ) { Do some thing}
```

How to convert this in to Power shell script? Also I would like to my new folder name is "EmailConnector Disc" there is white space in folder name. Let me know how to invoke the bat and write the output to one text file. BAT is simple script .
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell the code would look like this:

```
& 'D:\EmailConnector Disc\run.bat' > $emailconnecter_log
if ($LASTEXITCODE / 256) {
  # do something
}
```